# This simple code just won't compile

Tags: errors, amsthm, sourcecode, undefined, newtxmath

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
 \begin{proof}
 \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

This is the error I get:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
>   (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.12.17)  3 JUN 2020 17:21 entering
>   extended mode  restricted \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled.
>   **document.tex (./document.tex LaTeX2e <2018-12-01> (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document Class:
>   article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
>   (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo File: size10.clo
>   2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) \c@part=\count80
>   \c@section=\count81 \c@subsection=\count82 \c@subsubsection=\count83
>   \c@paragraph=\count84 \c@subparagraph=\count85 \c@figure=\count86
>   \c@table=\count87 \abovecaptionskip=\skip41 \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
>   \bibindent=\dimen102 )
>   (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty Package:
>   amsthm 2017/10/31 v2.20.4 \thm@style=\toks14 \thm@bodyfont=\toks15
>   \thm@headfont=\toks16 \thm@notefont=\toks17 \thm@headpunct=\toks18
>   \thm@preskip=\skip43 \thm@postskip=\skip44 \thm@headsep=\skip45
>   \dth@everypar=\toks19 ) (./document.aux) \openout1 = `document.aux'.
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line
>   5. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:
>   ... okay on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
>   OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
>   line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on
>   input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5. LaTeX Font
>   Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5. LaTeX
>   Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking
>   defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay
>   on input line 5.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \qedsymbol ->\openbox 
>                          l.7  \end{proof}
>                    The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,
>   `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
>   Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> [1
>
> {c:/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
>   (./document.aux) )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  301
>   strings out of 492616  3273 string characters out of 6132767  60701
>   words of memory out of 5000000  4294 multiletter control sequences out
>   of 15000+600000  3986 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000
>   for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191 
>   23i,4n,17p,116b,107s stack positions out of
>   5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
>   
>   Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 17026 bytes). PDF statistics: 
>   16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)  10 compressed objects
>   within 1 object stream  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
>   1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

This code is working though:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
 \begin{proof}
 \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

What's going on here?

Edit: this is what I see in my editor.

[image]

Comment: The first one works for me, but the second one doesn't. To make the second work you need to load `amsthm` first.

Comment: For some reason the first one doesn't work for me and the second one works whether amsthm comes first or newpxmath does...

Comment: Apparently, everything works fine as long as I don't use the "proof" environment without the newpxmath package.

Comment: Sorry, but I can only confirm Phelype's finding: the first code compiles, the second doesn't. I tried with TeX Live 2018. Can you please paste again the log file, but using the code markup just like for the sample documents?

Comment: @egreg I've edited my post, but I'm not sure that is what you're looking for. Is it helpful?

Comment: Installing TeX Live 2020 solved my issue. I have no idea what happened, but I'm glad everything is working fine now.